# Jquery Slidedown First

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with someone else html else I would of approached this differenty, but I'm trying to create a simple accordion from it.

The problem is it only slides show the first lot of div, it should find its parent div and slide show.

**JS**

```
  $('h3.jqueryheading').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('div:first').slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
   });
```

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="jqueryheading" style="cursor:pointer">Heading One</h3>
<div style="display:none;">
  <p><img src="one.jpg"/></p>
  <p><img src="two.jpg"/></p>
</div>

<h3 class="jqueryheading" style="cursor:pointer">Heading Two</h3>
<div style="display:none;">
  <p><img src="three.jpg"/></p>
  <p><img src="four.jpg"/></p>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Targeting the parent, then all DIV's gets you all the DIV's as they are children of the same parent, just target the `next()` DIV instead

```
$('h3.jqueryheading').click(function () {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLscF/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use next to target the next element

```
 $('h3.jqueryheading').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
```

});

Or the next div tag, if you want to be specific

```
 $('h3.jqueryheading').click(function() {
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
```

});

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kEycT/)

Answer (score 0):

Only one issue you have to use the :first-child or :eq(0)

```
$('h3.jqueryheading').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('div:eq(0)').slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
});
```

Comment: This still only opened the first one

Comment: can you input you code on js fiddle or something so i can try helping you better in this case?